# Accelerating diagonalization with GPU and multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, parallel-processing, cupy

In my python code, I have to diagonalize hundreds of arrays, each of size around ~1000*1000. However, each array is independent, so it would seem that I can accelerate this process using parallel programming. A minimal (pseudo-code) example would be something of the form

```
arr_list = [a0, a1, a2, ..., a199] # each arr is of shape 1000*1000
for idx, arr in enumerate(arr_list):
  evals, evecs  = np.linalg.eigh(arr)
  arr_list[idx] = evals
```

I'm not very familiar with CUDA, numba, CuPy or multiprocessing, but some quick research seems to tell me that CuPy is mainly used for accelerating basic operations such as addition, multiplication, diagonalization, etc. and only really has a significant jump in time relative to numpy if the array size is much larger than 1000. Multiprocessing, in contrast, seems to utilize the multiple cores (6-8) on a CPU, but it seems that numpy diagonalization is already a multi-core process (correct me if wrong), so it may not have a larger decrease in time.

I'm not very familiar with parallel programming, so I wondering if someone with more experience could give a few pointers on such a problem. Maybe a direction to research.

**EDIT**. Unfortunately, I'm on Windows so jax doesn't seem to work.

Comment: A related question: [Python 3: Parallel diagonalization of multiple matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26308953/1593077).

Comment: It may actually be the case that 1000x1000 is big enough for there not to be any benefit in parallelizing the diagonalization of multiple matrices, and you won't get any benefit over doing these all serially.

Comment: With CUDA you can look at the cuBlas and cuSolver libaries for suitable (batch) functions for diagonalization. Also think about any mathematical specialty of your matrices (sparse, symmetric, etc.), for which optimized algorithms exist. I would believe that a modern GPU is faster for this task than a CPU